# Connect to amazon Lightsail instance via SSH using linux terminal

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, terminal, amazon-lightsail

How can I connect to AWS LightSail instance?
AWS provides an web interface for doing this.
But how can I do this with my terminal with SSH.

There are lots of documentations available for connecting from Windows with Putty.

Answer (score 12):

1. Login to AWS account and navigate to [Lightsail Panel](https://lightsail.aws.amazaon.com)
2. At the `topbar`, click in `Account -> Account`.
3. Navigate to **SSH Keys** tab.
4. Download the SSH Keys of the instance you wish to connect.

> A `PEM` file with such naming is downloaded (e.g. `LightsailDefaultKey.pem`)

5. Move the file to a known location in your system.
6. Modify permissions for the file with below command

```sh
     chmod 400 LightsailDefaultKey.pem
```

7. Open the terminal in the same folder and use the below command.

```sh
ssh -i LightsailDefaultKey.pem user@<public-ip>
```

**Note**:

- Only the default key for a given Region is downloadable at any time.  For new keys, you can only store the `PEM` file when creating the key.

By the type of instance you have, use the corresponding username

- Amazon Linux, FreeBSD, openSUSE: ec2-user
- CentOS: centos
- Debian: admin
- Ubuntu: ubuntu
- Bitnami: bitnami
- Plesk: ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

use @kernelogy answer but make sure you set permission to your ssh key

```
chmod 400 LightsailDefaultKey.pem
```